# ESP8266 not responding after random intervals of time

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, http

**4th Update:**
I bought an ESP32 (the successor to ESP8266) and am getting the same problem. I used the same code except used the `Wifi.h` library instead, also removed the `ESP8266WiFiGratuitous.h` code. I added an LED flash at the start of the loop and can confirm the LED stops flashing, so I can confirm the `loop()` stops running.
This makes me think it must be something to do with my WIFI network.

**3rd update:**
I've removed all the code and instead uploaded a simple onboard LED blink sketch. The LED has been blinking for over 24 hrs which leads me to think there is something in the wifi code that is making the software crash.

**2nd update:**
I've even tried resetting the board at the start of the `loop()` body, every 10 mins, using the millisDelay.h library, calling this method to reset:

```
void(* resetFunc) (void) = 0;
```

but that doesn't help either. The `loop()` method seems to completey stop running.

**Update:**
I've added `experimental::ESP8266WiFiGratuitous::stationKeepAliveSetIntervalMs();` but am still failing to get a response after 1hr, with about 15 requests made in that hour.

I have this code which works on my ESP8266:

```cpp
    #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
    #include <ESP8266WiFiGratuitous.h>
    
    const size_t input_buffer_length = 256;
    
    const char* ssid = "iiNetC2DAD7";
    const char* wifiPassword = "aM9PrxcbtkS";
    const char* passwordToOpenDoor = "/87"; //password should begin with a slash
    
    const int doorPin = 5;
    const int buzzerPin = 4;
    const int toneDuration = 700;
    
    int numOfRequests = 0;
    
    WiFiServer server(301); //Pick any port number you like
    WiFiClient client;
    
    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(115200);
      delay(10);
      Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
      
      pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, 1);
    
      pinMode(doorPin, OUTPUT);
      digitalWrite(doorPin, 0);
    
      pinMode(buzzerPin, OUTPUT);
      digitalWrite(buzzerPin, 0);
    
      Serial.println();
      Serial.print("Connecting to ");
      Serial.println(ssid);
    
      WiFi.begin(ssid, wifiPassword); 
    
      while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
      }
      Serial.println("");
      Serial.println("WiFi connected");
    
      experimental::ESP8266WiFiGratuitous::stationKeepAliveSetIntervalMs();
    
      server.begin();
      Serial.println("Server started.");
      Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    }
    
    void loop() {
      client = server.available();
      if (!client) {    
        return;
      }
    
      while(!client.available()){
        delay(1);  
      }
        
      char request[input_buffer_length];
      client.readBytesUntil('\r', request, input_buffer_length);  
      Serial.println(request);
      
      if(strstr(request, passwordToOpenDoor)) {//Is password correct?
        GenerateResponse("Password is correct");
        OpenDoor();
        CorrectPasswordSound();
      }
      //Got a GET request and it wasn't the favicon.ico request, must have been a bad password:
      else if (!strstr(request, "favicon.ico")) {
        GenerateResponse("Password is incorrect.");
      }  
    }
    
    void OpenDoor() {
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, 0); //flash the onboard LED to help during testing.
      digitalWrite(doorPin, 1);
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, 1);
      digitalWrite(doorPin, 0);
    }
    
    void GenerateResponse(const char *text) {
      Serial.println(text);
      client.print(
          "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
          "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
          "\r\n"
          "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\r\n"
          "<html>\r\n"
          "<br><h1><b>"
      );
      client.print(text);
      client.print("</b></h1><br><h1><b>Num of requests: ");
      client.print(++numOfRequests);  
      client.print("</b></h1></html>\r\n");
      client.flush();  
    }
    
    void CorrectPasswordSound() {
      //Play 1700, 1800, 1900Hz
      for(int i = 17; i < 20; i++){
        int frequency = i * 100;
        tone(buzzerPin, frequency);
        delay(toneDuration);
        noTone(buzzerPin);
      }
    }
```

- However, after a random amount of time, the software crashes and the device won't respond to HTTP requests anymore.
- I've tested this by printing to the serial monitor every loop. It seems as though it crashes and the `loop()` function stops running since it stops printing to the monitor.
- I noticed that it'll still reply to pings.
- It won't reconnect after restarting the router, I need to press the reset button on the ESP8266 to get it to start working again.
- I've tested it by sending an HTTP Get request every 5 mins for many hours (using a C# console app). Sometimes it failed after 45 mins, sometimes 7 hours.
- I initially thought it was because I was using String objects, but after getting an answer to this [question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/75450/how-to-replace-string-objects-with-char-arrays-while-still-using-string-methods) and testing it out with only C-strings, I still have the same problem.
- I've been sending HTTP Get requests using Chrome on my phone and laptop, as well as the .NET Framework class `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`.

Spec:

- Board: AI-Thinker ESP8266MOD
- IDE: Arduino 1.8.12
- ESP8266 Boards version = 2.6.3
- IDE Settings:

[image]

I've tried resetting the connection using:

```
server.stop();
delay(1000);
server.begin();
```

Then this:

```
ESP.reset();
```

Then after those 2 didn't work, this:

```
ESP.restart();
```

Resetting it frequently did nothing.

Is there anything in my code that stands out?
If there's nothing wrong withe code, then maybe my only option is to hard reset the board every 30 mins some how.

Comment: Your code looks okay. A couple of suggestions. 1) move the WiFiClient client; into the loop() and can combined with server.available(); to form a one liner like this WiFiClient client = server.available();. 2) the only time that the loop() seems to stop running will be the time where if (!client) { return;} which is actually when server is not available. I would suggest instead of simply return, you print something out before the return to see if that's what happening.

Comment: @hcheung but then client won't be recognised in the GenerateResponse() function.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I guess it has to be at Global then.

Comment: make the WiFiClient a local variable. pass it to function as reference. `void GenerateResponse(WiFiClient& client, const char *text) {`

Comment: @Juraj will that provide any benefits?

Comment: in past there was a problem with a memory leak if the client object was reused

Comment: Have you ruled out any hardware issues, like marginal power supplies, bad connections,  etc? What does enabling the doorPin do?

Comment: @StarCat I'm going to try just turning the LED on and off, no wifi or anything and see what happens. The doorPin just turns on a relay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is your problem, but I'll leave it here because it is certainly a potential bug.

This code in loop:

```
  while(!client.available()){
    delay(1);  
  }
```

can cause a deadlock if you have a client that drops or doesn't talk.  Turn that around and let the loop keep running.

```
boolean haveClient = false;

void loop() {
  client = server.available();
  if (client) {    
    haveClient = true;
  } else {
    haveClient = false;
  }

  if(haveClient && client.available()){

     // The rest of your loop where you read
     //  from the client goes inside here.
```

That way if you get a client and then available keeps returning false you can at least keep checking for a client.

This may not be and is not intended to be a code solution. This is probably not the best way to code what I'm trying to say.  I don't know if server.available will keep giving you back the same client or if it is going to cut you off to call that again before the client disconnects.  There may be some method in there to check the connection.  Either way, that's not the point.  The point is to never capture your code into a locked up while loop.  That is always asking for a deadlock.  It's bad practice except for cases like fatal errors where you truly want to lock the thing up.  Let the loop keep looping.  Use if statements to decide which parts get run when.

If you want to check that this is where you are locking up, put some sort of output before and after that while loop.  Print something or turn a light on before and off after.  That way you can tell if this is the spot you're locking up.

Comment: After implementing your change, it's worked the longest it ever has, over 7hrs!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Delta_G for pointing me in the right direction.
The trick was to not get stuck in the `loop()` function, ie. no while loops.

The problem was that after you run `client = server.available();`, the client needs some time before `client.available()` returns true, which is what the while loop is for, **however**, for some reason, the client would lose its connection every now and then and `client.available()` would never return true, in which case you get stuck in the while loop. You need to give it a second chance and let the process start again.

By delaying about 50ms, it seems to be enough time for the client to establish a connection, and if it doesn't, it loops and tries again so quickly that it appears as though the client always gets the connection and the code works fine.

Here's the working code:

```
void loop() {      
  WiFiClient client = server.available();

  if(client){
    delay(50);
    if(client.available()) {
        //rest of code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the similar problem especially when the WIFI signal is weak. The connection drop prematurely, end up the software execution is stuck within the while(!client.available()) loop.

A fail-safe timer can be implemented to get out from this loop as follow:

```
  unsigned int u32FailSafeTimer = 3000;   /*Set 3s timeout*/
  while(!client.available())
  {
    u32FailSafeTimer--;
    delay(1);   /*pause for 1ms*/
    if (0 == u32FailSafeTimer)   /*Fail-safe timer elapsed, get out from unexpected error*/
    {
      Serial.printf("timeout (RSSI: %d dBm)\n\n", WiFi.RSSI());
      client.flush();   /*Kill and prepare for next session*/
      return;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be the "server unreachable after a while" problem, which is solved solved by sending gratuitous ARP requests. In the esp8266 Arduino core 2.7 they added functions for this. The main function is `experimental::ESP8266WiFiGratuitous::stationKeepAliveSetIntervalMs();`. Include `<#include "ESP8266WiFiGratuitous.h>`

Notes:

- You don't know if your loop stops. It doesn't print anything if no client can reach it.
- remove the flush() after readBytesUntil(). it doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: You means [stationKeepAliveSetIntervalMs](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/src/ESP8266WiFiGratuitous.h#L37)? or it is at somewhere else in the source code?

Comment: sorry it changed on the way from PR to release. yes `stationKeepAliveSetIntervalMs `

Comment: How do I read the password in the request URL without using readBytesUntil()?

Comment: Juraj is suggesting to delete the `client.flush()`, not the client.readBytesUntil().

Comment: Sorry! Misread the answer.

Comment: @DavidKlempfner, in setup() after successful connection to AP

Comment: Where do I put this line of code?:
WiFi.stationKeepAliveSetIntervalMs(interval).I tried "WiFi.stationKeepAliveSetIntervalMs(1000);" after "WiFi.begin(ssid, wifiPassword);" but got
'class ESP8266WiFiClass' has no member named 'stationKeepAliveSetIntervalMs'

Comment: and did you update to 2.7.0?

Comment: Yeah I updated the board manager ESP8266 to 2.7. Are there any extra #includes I need to add?

Comment: sorry I updated the answer. it is still an experimental function

Comment: @Juraj please see my updated question. I added that code but it still failed after 1hr.

Comment: @Juraj I tested again, it worked for 5.5hrs and did 82 requests before it timed out.

Answer (score 0):

I will take a SWAG and say it sounds like the watchdog may be getting you. I was getting similar problems but nothing to do with WiFi or anything like that. I determined that when it got stuck in a loop it would sit for a while and then crash. I was able to determine (guess) something was timing out and since the external hardware did not reset and yet it would run setup() again the processor was resetting itself. It would hang with some things appearing to work. After I dug down into it I found that I had to release my code to allow the watchdog to be reset by the internal ESP software. I based this on some information I found about the maximum time allowed for the delay() function. Hopefully this helps.